# What happens when call Node.appendChild() to add a script tag?

Tags: javascript, web, dom

I am trying to load a function from a script tag in an external page, but I want to bind them  a new context. (`this` points to the host element in the snippet)

```
this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(template)
const scriptNode = document.createElement('script')
scriptNode.innerHTML = script.textContent
scriptNode.async = false
this.shadowRoot.appendChild(scriptNode)
render.call(this)
```

This works the way I want, but first I polluted the global environment, and I am not so sure what really happens when the script tag added to the host.

Can I safely assume the script will always be executed first before the next line is called(`render.call`)?

Also, do we have a better way to load some script from other files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it as a best practice, since I don't know if there are better solutions (and of course there will be with the new javascript modules), but you can try something like this:

```
scriptNode.innerHTML = '(function () { ' + script.textContent + ' }).apply(/*this*/ window)';
```

Comment: I could have misunderstood the question, tell me if I didn't get it so I delete my answer

Comment: It does not introduce global variables any more, but I cannot bind a new context to it in this way. I don't want to bind window to it , but something else within this snippet scope.

Comment: `window` was just an example, you can pass everything you want